# How to access GitLens+ features for a public fork?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscodium, gitlens

I created a public fork of a public repository on GitHub. After cloning via SSH I can't use the Commit Graph feature of the GitLens VSCode plugin. It says:

> A trial or paid plan is required to use this on privately hosted repos.

Why is that? Which repositories are considered public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitLens FAQ](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitlens/gitlens-faq/) mentions:

> Yes, all features are free to use on all repos, except for features:
>
> - marked with a ✨ require a trial or paid plan for use on privately hosted repos
> - marked with a ☁️ require a GitKraken Account, with access level based on your plan, e.g. Free, Pro, etc

The [Commit Graph feature](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitlens/gitlens-features/#commit-graph-%e2%9c%a8) is marked ✨.

So this is:

- either a bug (a fork of a public repository is public)
- or a fork is considered by GitLens as "private use" somehow.

As a test, try and create your own public empty repository, and import through a remote named "upstream" the repository you intended to fork: check if the Commit Graph feature is available then.

---

As the OP comments:

> - firstly you clone via `git clone https://github.com/me/fork.git`, the extension sees that the repo is public,
> - then you type `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:me/fork.git` and the extension continues to work.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in SSH. Seems like if I clone via HTTPS `git clone https://github.com/me/fork.git` the extension is able to check if the repo is private or not, but if I use `git clone git@github.com:me/fork.git` then it's stuck and makes it private by default. Can I somehow clone via HTTPS making the extension work and then change the remote to SSH so everything works as if I cloned via SSH?

Comment: OK, so firstly you clone via `git clone https://github.com/me/fork.git`, the extension sees that the repo is public, then you type `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:me/fork.git` and the extension continues to work!

Comment: You can, with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:me/myfork`.

Comment: Exactly, I have edited the answer to include your comment. Good catch!